# Moving an element down a bit

Tags: html, css

I made a template for a login page and I think so far it looks pretty good! But I'm stuck on two things. I want to move the whole login "box" down about 25px and the "Login" button dow about 10-20px. How can I do this?

[image]

CSS and HTML code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #224b65;
}
#boxTitle {
  background-color: #ffd11a;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 0px solid #ffd11a;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
#infoBoxes {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Please Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="boxTitle">
        <h1 class="loginTitle">Please Login</h1>
      </div>
        <div id="infoBoxes">
          <form>
              <h3 class="usernameText">Username</h3><input type="text" class="usernameBox" />
              <h3 class="passwordText">Password</h3><input type="password" class="passwordBox" />
              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use template .. https://colorlib.com/wp/html5-and-css3-login-forms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `margin-top` property to add space above an element:

```
#boxTitle {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think isn't this what you need, cause it's too easy, just adding margin-top

```css
body {
  background-color: #224b65;
}
#content{
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#boxTitle {
  background-color: #ffd11a;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 0px solid #ffd11a;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
#infoBoxes {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Please Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="boxTitle">
        <h1 class="loginTitle">Please Login</h1>
      </div>
        <div id="infoBoxes">
          <form>
              <h3 class="usernameText">Username</h3><input type="text" class="usernameBox" />
              <h3 class="passwordText">Password</h3><input type="password" class="passwordBox" />
              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```